# How do mixed definitions work in enum?

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I am trying to use a C program (via dynamic libraries) with Python and the ctypes module. Several constants defined in a header file will be important for me, but I am unsure of how `enum` is being used to set their values.

The obvious ones, I think I understand like:
`enum{THING1, THING2, THING3};`

`THING1=0, THING2=1, THING3=3`

But, what about this?
`enum{THING1=-1, THING2, THING3};`

Is the result:
`THING1=-1, THING2=1, THING3=2`?

What about this one?
`enum{THING1=1, THING2, THING3, THING4=-1}`?

I don't have an easy way to test this, so hoping someone can explain the way `enum` works in this context. C books I looked in seemed to cover either the first case or the case where each value is explicitly defined, but not this mixed case.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of the first `enum` constant is 0, unless specified otherwise.

The value of any other `enum` constant is one more than the value of the previous, unless it is explicitly specified.

So

```
enum{THING1=-1, THING2, THING3};
```

sets `THING2 = 0, THING3 = 1`, and

```
enum{THING1=1, THING2, THING3, THING4=-1}
```

sets `THING2 = 2, THING3 = 3` (and `THING4 = -1` is explicitly given).

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! To take this to the extreme, then, would enum{THING1=-10,THING2,THING3=500,THING4} give: THING1=-10, THING2=-9, THING3=500, and THING4=501? The header file I'm using is full of all sorts of mixtures like this.

Comment: Yes, that's what that declaration would produce. Such mixtures seem odd, though. Normally, `enum` constants are sequential or bit-flags.

Comment: Thanks again Daniel. You helped me a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

They just get incremented from the previous value. In your example,

```
enum{THING1=-1, THING2, THING3};
```

is equivalent to

```
enum{THING1=-1, THING2=0, THING3=1};
```

And this one

```
enum{THING1=1, THING2, THING3, THING4=-1}?
```

is equivalent to

```
enum{THING1=1, THING2=2, THING3=3, THING4=-1}
```